# Routing everything that is not explicitly routed to a specific controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

In CakePHP I want to do specific routing rules (mainly out of beauty and SEO reasons).

So for example, what I do in my code is something like this:

```
Router::connect('/c/:uni.html', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action'=>'index'));
```

Now if somebody would call

> MY_SITE/anyController/anyAction

I do NOT want CakePHP to go there, even if this Controller really does exist (and of course the action too...)

Example:

```
class AnyController extends AppController {
    var $helper = array('Html');

    /**
     * landingpage
     */
    private function anyAction() {
        //this action must not be called by /anyController/anyAction
                    //but only by my own defined route
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like this would make it an absolute pita to work on the project - what about ajax calls - requestActions...etc etc - you're going to write a route for EVERY action that needs to be hit via URL?  (sorry, I know this isn't an answer...)

Comment: That's not a big deal. Guess it's something like writing about 20 or 30 Rules cause you can catch multiple ones by making good rules like ":a/:b/:c". I dont see the issue in here.
My Problem is at all: duplicate content avoiding.

Comment: canonical links is the correct way to achieve this. If you insist on coding every possible route and want to prevent anything else from working, remove the default routes from `routes.php` (the require). Then ONLY routes you define will work; everything else will 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to duplicate content is usually a 'canonical link' tag, as @dogmatic69 points out.

Putting such a tag on all of your pages, you can get the best of both worlds: keep Cake's default routes, but point search engines to the 'right' URL.

This is how you insert a canonical link tag in your view:

```
echo $this->Html->meta(
    'canonical',
    'http://example.com',
    array(
        'rel' => 'canonical',
        'type' => null,
        'title' => null,
        'inline' => false
     )
 );
```

Instead of `http://example.com` you can use Cake's `url()` function, that can take an action and a controller as parameters and will always return your custom route (this is called [reverse routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#reverse-routing)).

```
$this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'foo',
    'action' => 'bar'
));
```

Putting it all together, this should give you what you want:

```
echo $this->Html->meta(
    'canonical',
    $this->Html->url(array(
        'controller' => $this->request->params['controller'],
        'action' => $this->request->params['action']
    )),
    array(
        'rel' => 'canonical',
        'type' => null,
        'title' => null,
        'inline' => false
     )
 );
```

This puts the first (your preferred) route of the current view's controller/action into a canonical link tag.

Comment: Okay that's what I already thought about. I think I'm gonna extend the helper like this. thx

Answer (score 1):

Just create a route that catches everything

```
// your other routes

Router::connect('/*', array('contoler' => '...);
```

As pointed out in the comments, this is not a great idea. It does have uses though.

Comment: Yep, I know that this is no "good" solution. BUT: How do you do it? You dont want the page A to be accessed on 2 different ways, do you?

Comment: That is what [canonical urls](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps) are for. Cake will always generate the url with the first matching route, so you wont end up with different urls to the same place when creating links with arrays.

Comment: can you point that out? I did not find anything that Cake is generating Canonicals automatically. I know that I could do it manually but thats no good solution either.